# How should I copy file from one FTP server to other FTP server using ANT

Tags: ant, ftp

Is is possible to copy one "xyz.rpt" file from FTP Server "X" to FTP Server "Y" using ANT ?

Should we achieve it using FTP Task of ANT?

Comment: It should be possible, but you will have to copy it from X to your local server, and then on to Y using two ftp tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ftp task available:
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html

You will indeed need to tranfer the file via your local machine, in 2 subsequent ftp tasks.

Example:

```
 <ftp server="ftp.hypothetical.india.org"
   port="2121"
   remotedir="/pub/incoming"
   userid="coder"
   password="java1"
   depends="yes"
   binary="no"
   systemTypeKey="Windows"
   serverTimeZoneConfig="India/Calcutta">
<fileset dir="htdocs/manual">
  <include name="**/*.html"/>
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change FTP Service Status**

Command to check status list:

```
inetadm
```

or specific (ftp) service;

```
svcs ftp
```

If your status is offline or disabled, you must change your status to enable. To do that:

```
svcadm -v enable network/ftp
svcadm refresh svc:/network/ftp:default
svcadm restart svc:/network/ftp:default
```

Check your status again:

```
svcs ftp
```

After enabling ftp service;

If you defined before like a target, you need to do somethings like that;

```
<target name="sendSetup">
     <ftp action="mkdir"
          server="${app.srv.name}"
          userid="${app.srv.user.name}"
          passive="yes"
          password="${app.srv.passwd}"
          remotedir="/xxx/xxx/Builds/${branch.env}/${build.label}"
          ignoreNoncriticalErrors="true" />
</target>
```